# Why did Old Norse influence English more than Saxon and Jutish?

Tags: germanic-languages, old-english

I read a lot of etymologies but I don't remember reading about words that came from Saxon language or Jutish language, nearly all Germanic words who have non English origins came from Old Norse or Dutch or German.

Why it's called Anglo-Saxon if there are no enough words that came from Saxon?

I think Saxon and Jutish influenced only certain dialects of Angles, am I right?

I don't understand what have Saxon, Jutish and Frisian to do with the language of Angles except they're cousin languages.

Comment: I think you’re misunderstanding what Old English, Anglo-Saxon and Saxon are. There is a separate Saxon language in Continental Europe, but Old English itself is _also_ Saxon… sort of. Saxon, Anglic and Frisian together make up the Ingvaeonic group, and they were very close to each other. Anglic and Frisian share some common innovations, but Anglic and Saxon also have some in common. Old English is called Anglo-Saxon because it’s ‘the form of Saxon found in England’, roughly. Virtually any word that would have been _borrowed_ into Old English from Saxon would end up being indistinguishable ->

Comment: -> from an inherited word, so we can almost never say for sure whether a word is inherited or borrowed from Saxon – so we generally assume it’s just English. In other words, the reason why so few words have Saxon in their etymology when you look them up is that for etymological purposes, Old English ≈ Saxon.

Comment: What do you meany by inherited ? sorry I'm not a native speaker of English.

Comment: ‘Inherited’ is just the opposite of ‘borrowed’, so what you’d call ‘words with English origins’ are inherited words, while ‘words with non-English origins’ are borrowed/loan words. So generally speaking, Saxon words would be considered words with English origins, not loan words.

Comment: I would express this a little differently.  The "English" were a combination of three closely related continental ethnic groups from what is now Denmark and Germany: the Angles, Saxons, and Jutes.  The three ethnic groups founded more than three kingdoms in England, and so whatever tribal affiliation may have been felt was superseded by the new political entities.  In Latin, they were all called *Anglii*, and after King Alfred's partial unification, I think the name English became predominant, leaving place names such as Wessex, Essex, and East Anglia referring to defunct ethnicities.

Comment: I should add that I think the term "Old English" is probably more popular currently than "Anglo-Saxon," but the fact that they mean the same thing shows that you will not find a clear separation of Angle and Saxon elements by the time of the earliest documents.  I believe the Jutes were a much smaller proportion of the population and so their name lives on only in modern Denmark.  The term Frisian applies only to groups that remained on the continent and so is not part of the terms "Old English" and "Anglo-Saxon," even if their languages/dialects are closely related.

Comment: @Vegawatcher Jutes do seem to have formed the majority in Kent and the Isle of Wight. Place name evidence also suggests significant Frisian presence across England, but within territories dominated by Angles, Saxons, or Jutes, rather than forming their own polities